# Fade in Fade out Effect AngularJS Directive For ngStyle

Tags: css, angularjs, image, background

I am creating a simple background-image slideshow directive using angular js. Everything works fine , however I want an elegant fadeIn fadeOut effect when the background image changes. Any idea how I can achieve this. Code is below

```
angular.module("shouvikme").directive('bgSlider', function ($interval) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs)
    {

        var bg_array = ['bg1.jpg', 'bg2.jpg', 'bg3.jpg', 'bg4.jpg'];
        var i = -1;
        $interval(function ()
        {
            i>=bg_array.length-1 ? i=0 : i++;
            var bg_string = "url('assets/img/overlays/black-overlay.png'), url('assets/img/banners/" + bg_array[i] + "')";
            element.css({ 'background': bg_string });
            element.css({'background-size': 'auto, cover'});
            element.css({'background-position': 'top left, center center'});
            element.css({'background-repeat': 'repeat, no-repeat'});
            element.css({'background-attachment': 'fixed'});
        }, 5000);



    };
});
```